# How to plot 2 lines in same graphs in R ggplot2 with small values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have following data in csv format

```
0.828666667 0.100333333
0.725666667 0.153666667
0.364333333 0.036666667
0.475666667 0.051    
0.522333333 0.052333333    
0.457   0.041666667    
0.644666667 0.093333333    
0.404333333 0.039333333    
0.497   0.042333333    
0.155666667 0.031666667    
0.160666667 0.081333333    
0.145666667 0.026666667    
0.138666667 0.033666667    
0.094333333 0.03    
0.141   0.023666667    
0.148666667 0.052    
0.195666667 0.039    
0.196333333 0.039333333
......
```

I am using following code

```
library(ggplot2)
data<-read.csv("sample.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
ggplot(data,aes(x=A,y=B,))+ geom_line() + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,9,0.5)) + 
scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,9,0.5))
```

I want have same scale in x and y axis thats y i am using breaks..but this doesnt give what i want it does over plotting

[image]

But i want to image as follows see example second image[image]

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to manipulate the data a little bit...

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- YOUR CSV
names(dat) <- c('a', 'b')

# need an x for the plot 
dat$Num <- as.numeric(row.names(dat))

meltDat <- melt(dat, id.vars = 'Num')

ggplot(meltDat, 
       aes(x = Num, y = value, group = variable, color = variable)) +
geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply i tried your code for my data now but i get one error at the stage meltDat <- melt(dat, id.vars = 'Num') (Error: id variables not found in data: Num). As i am new to ggplot not getting how to solve it. And one more thing is how to edit y axis as same as x axis i mean i want this y axis same as 0 to 15 scaling

Comment: sorry about that... R is case sensitive and the `num` variable was in lower case.  it should work now.  i'm not sure i understand your second point, but i would look into `xlim` & `ylim` if you're looking to focus on specific intervals?

Comment: Thanks for solution :) in the second point i ment as follows in the data what i have 2 columns which ranges from 0 to 15 (when i see values in both the columns) so i want same scales in both x and y axis with 0 to 15.. to acheive this i did following ggplot(meltDat,aes(x=num,y = value, group = variable, color = variable)) + xlim(0,15) + ylim(0,15) + geom_line()... but it gives some warning as : Removed 330 rows containing missing values (geom_path) so can please tell me am i deleting an data while plotting? thanks

Comment: Are the columns you are trying to plot the x- & y- coordinates?  According to your chart, you would have three columns

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want to do. But here's my attempt to get from your data to something similar to your second plot.

```
data <- read.table(text="0.828666667 0.100333333
0.725666667 0.153666667
0.364333333 0.036666667
0.475666667 0.051    
0.522333333 0.052333333    
0.457   0.041666667    
0.644666667 0.093333333    
0.404333333 0.039333333    
0.497   0.042333333    
0.155666667 0.031666667    
0.160666667 0.081333333    
0.145666667 0.026666667    
0.138666667 0.033666667    
0.094333333 0.03    
0.141   0.023666667    
0.148666667 0.052    
0.195666667 0.039    
0.196333333 0.039333333")
names(data) <- c("A", "B")
# prepare data for plotting
require(reshape2)
data$id <- 1:nrow(data)
df <- melt(data, id.var="id")
# plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=id, y=value, color=variable)) + geom_line()
```

If this did not answer your question, please try to be more specific.